# How does python3.11's StrEnum's MRO work differently for __str__ and __repr__?

Tags: python, inheritance, enums, method-resolution-order

Python3.11 introduced `StrEnum` and `IntEnum` which inherit `str` or `int` respectively, and also inherit `ReprEnum`, which in turn inherits `Enum`.

`ReprEnum`'s implementation is actually empty.

```py
>>> print(inspect.getsource(ReprEnum))
class ReprEnum(Enum):
    """
    Only changes the repr(), leaving str() and format() to the mixed-in type.
    """
```

If I create a `StrEnum` and check the MRO, I can see that `str` comes first.

```py
class Strings(StrEnum):
    A = "a"
```

```py
>>> Strings.__mro__
(<enum 'Strings'>, <enum 'StrEnum'>, <class 'str'>, <enum 'ReprEnum'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>)
```

Both `str` and `Enum` define a `__str__` and a `__repr__`

```py
>>> str.__repr__
<slot wrapper '__repr__' of 'str' objects>
>>> str.__str__
<slot wrapper '__str__' of 'str' objects>
>>> Enum.__repr__
<function Enum.__repr__ at 0x7ffff69f72e0>
>>> Enum.__str__
<function Enum.__str__ at 0x7ffff69f7380>
```

How then does `__repr__` get inherited from `Enum` and `__str__` get inherited from `str`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__repr__` method comes the normal way, inherited from `Enum` (via `StrEnum`)

```
>>> Strings.__repr__ is StrEnum.__repr__ is Enum.__repr__
True
```

For the `__str__` method, the metaclass `EnumType` checks for the presence of `ReprEnum` and "hoists up" the `str` and `format` handling of the mixed-in data type into the class namespace at class definition time [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.4/Lib/enum.py#L575-L592):

```
class EnumType(type):

    ...

    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, classdict, *, boundary=None, _simple=False, **kwds):

        ...

        # Also, special handling for ReprEnum
        if ReprEnum is not None and ReprEnum in bases:
            if member_type is object:
                raise TypeError(
                        'ReprEnum subclasses must be mixed with a data type (i.e.'
                        ' int, str, float, etc.)'
                        )
            if '__format__' not in classdict:
                enum_class.__format__ = member_type.__format__
                classdict['__format__'] = enum_class.__format__
            if '__str__' not in classdict:
                method = member_type.__str__
                if method is object.__str__:
                    # if member_type does not define __str__, object.__str__ will use
                    # its __repr__ instead, so we'll also use its __repr__
                    method = member_type.__repr__
                enum_class.__str__ = method
                classdict['__str__'] = enum_class.__str__

        ...
```

Now that a `Strings.__str__` method may be found directly in the class namespace, the MRO needn't be traversed.